# I get error message from Pip problem installing packages 3.8.3

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I install a package using pip, I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"d:\python.exe"  "D:\Scripts\pip.exe" install python-telegram-bot': Impossibile trovare il file specificato.
```

EDIT:
Impossibile trovare il file specificato. means Impossible to find specified file.
I already tried reinstalling and it didn't worked.
How can I fix this error? It occurs with every module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding 'python -m ' before pip. This sometimes fixes.

```
C:\Users\jupit>python -m pip install python-telegram-bot
Collecting python-telegram-bot
  Downloading python_telegram_bot-12.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (375 kB)
```

Try 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' too, if pip is broken.

Comment: I know that feeling, pip is problematic sometimes. Glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Spanish, but I think the error is saying that pip doesn't exist on your file system. Try reinstalling it, or Python as a whole, then reinstalling both. Make sure pip is selected in the installation menu, like [so](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/xq90/922/O0ydCp.jpg).